# How to weld clothes but keep seams of clothes imported from Marvelous Designer?

Tags: cloth-simulation, seams

When I import clothes from Marvelous Designer I like to keep the seams of clothes that are sewed. Right now to do that is to import them as 1 object but unsewed so blender sees them as separate objects. Problem with this is that when I try to do a cloth simulation things fall apart.
If I use the weld modifier, the seams are gone. Is there a way to weld them together to do a cloth simulation on the clothes (hoodie in this example) but keep the seams?

Without weld:
[image]

With weld on hoodie:
[image]

Comment: I would recommend surface deform modifier from a non-rendering, joined copy with merged vertices.  However, I'd wonder why you want them to be separate objects; there may be some other way to get whatever that gets you.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into the surface deform modifier and it could indeed help out. If I export from Marvelous Designer as 1 object welded, then you get the problem in picture 2 where the seams are gone. That's why I export it as multiple objects in one. I need to look into some things to fix it, cause adding a cloth simulation is pretty hard imo to get it right. Thank you for giving me more insight!

Comment: Assuming that the export without seams isn't actually destroying any vertices, then the only difference between the two is in the normals, and you can use custom split normals instead of doing a surface deform.  That'd be preferable for a number of reasons.